# mysql combine multiple columns in each row into a single column in each row

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I have a table (pic #1) with a foreign key to another table.  This table only includes the FK/Id to the other table, there are 5 columns.  There might not always be a value, so if there isn't I insert a -1, this is done in a datagridview vb.net. There is a name associated with each id.  So, in the table with the FK's (pic #1) is there a way to query the names for each id and then join/concatenate into one column for each row?  I was able to do a query and return each name separately (pic #2), but couldn't quite figure out how to join all 5.  I'm quite new to all of this, so please tell me if I'm off my rocker and I need to approach differently.  Thank you.

```
SELECT 
s.id,
g1.name as Grade1_name,
g2.name as Grade2_name,
g3.name as Grade3_name,
g4.name as Grade4_name,
g5.name as Grade5_name,
s.Grades_Name
FROM
sort s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
grades g1 ON g1.id = s.grade_id_1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
grades g2 ON g2.id = s.grade_id_2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
grades g3 ON g3.id = s.grade_id_3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
grades g4 ON g4.id = s.grade_id_4
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
grades g5 ON g5.id = s.grade_id_5
```

[pic #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7yEr.png)
[pic #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGfuS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with this.  Not sure if this is good code or not, but it does what I need.

```
SELECT 
s.id,
CONCAT_WS(", ", g1.name, g2.name, g3.name, g4.name, g5.name) AS GradeNames
FROM
sort s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
grades g1 ON g1.id = s.grade_id_1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
grades g2 ON g2.id = s.grade_id_2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
grades g3 ON g3.id = s.grade_id_3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
grades g4 ON g4.id = s.grade_id_4
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
grades g5 ON g5.id = s.grade_id_5
```